# AVFoundation & Video Effects

Tags: video, avfoundation, cifilter

I'm trying myself on some video-editing, I got sequencing and mixing video/audio together all working properly, even some basic slow-mo! :)
Now I want to integrate video filters, not only to the layer itself (elsewise I would have use AVPlayerItemVideoOutput in company with an CIFilter) but also in the final video file that gets exported.
Therefore I'm currently looking into "rendering" the CIFilter I mentioned above into the final video while still keeping very precise control over timing using CMTime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to find a straight forward solution to this problem ? One approach would be to write a custom implementation of AVAssetExportSession using AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter, but that would involve a lot of work.

Comment: Look at GPUImageFilter, it's just great.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [AVVideoCompositing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositing_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest/sourceFrameByTrackID:) protocol to implement a custom compositor.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest sourceFrameByTrackID:trackID];
CIImage *theImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
CIImage *motionBlurredImage = [[CIFilter *filterWithName:@"CIMotionBlur" keysAndValues:@"inputImage", theImage, nil] valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CIContext *someCIContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:eaglContext];
[someCIContext render:motionBlurredImage toCVPixelBuffer:outputBuffer];
```

Then render the pixel buffer using OpenGL as described in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html). This would allow you to implement any number of transitions or filters that you want.

Comment: is there any sample projects on how to do this out there?

Comment: Okay I found a sample project in the ios developer library for he who finds this next, AVCustomEdit at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A WWDC talk from 2015 explains how this can be done.

Start watching from 20:32 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/510/

*Exporting:*

Step 01:

```
let vidComp = AVVideoComposition(asset: avAsset,
    applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: {
    request in
        filtered = request.sourceImage.imageByClampingToExtent();
        filtered = filtered.imageByApplyingFilter("CIGaussianBlur",
            withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 100])
        filtered = filtered.imageByCroppingToRect(request.sourceImage.extent)
        request.finishWithImage(filtered, context: cicontext)
 })
```

Step 02:

```
let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset,
    presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080)
export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
export.outputURL = outURL
export.videoComposition = vidComp
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(outURL)
export.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler()
```

*Playback:*

Step 01:

```
let vidComp = AVVideoComposition(asset: avAsset,
    applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: {
 // same as earlier example
 })
```

Step 02:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
playerItem.videoComposition = vidComp
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.play()
```

Jonathan's answer is also correct. However, Apple has now discontinued use of OpenGL. Below is the same code in Swift using Metal,

```
let theImage = CIImage.init(cvImageBuffer: foregroundPixelBuffer)

let blurFilter = CIFilter.init(name: "CIMotionBlur")
blurFilter?.setValue(theImage, forKey: "inputImage")

if let destinationImage = blurFilter?.outputImage {
    context?.render(destinationImage, to: outputBuffer)
}
```

Context should be declared as follows,

```
context = CIContext.init(mtlDevice: device)
```

and device as follows,

```
// Ask for the default Metal device; this represents our GPU.
guard let defaultMetalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
    print("Metal is not supported on this device.")
    return nil
}
device = defaultMetalDevice
```

Context and device instances should be declared once and re-used to benefit from their caching abilities.